# How to add icon into Java (NetBeans) from Mac Os X?

Tags: java, macos, swing, jlabel, imageicon

So I'm trying to add an icon into my program, but the textbook I'm reading explain how to only for Windows users. I would like to know how to add the icon. I have it on my program source folder and the code I have so far is something like this:

```
logo = new ImageIcon("~://resources//CherryBoom.png");

labelone = new JLabel("Fruit No.1 : ", logo, SwingConstants.LEFT);
JPanel panelone = new JPanel();
panelone.add(labelone, logo);
```

The icon still won't show on the windows panel, so I'm really lost here, and I don't know how can I get it to show into my program.

Comment: I'm not sure that Java is capable of processing the "~" directive

Comment: You both helped me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check the obvious solutions such as:

- Have you done `window.add(panelone);`
- Is the file in the correct spot/url is correct

Secondly, if you hate LayoutManagers like me, but still want to use `javax.swing`, you might try using `drawString` and `drawImage` methods in your panel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` class. In detail:

You'll need to make your own JPanel:

`public class MyPanel extends JPanel {`

as well as override the method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

within the method, call this so the window can refresh itself and do other housekeeping things:

`super.paintComponent(g);`

then, use drawString and drawImage to draw these images in the place you would like them:

```
g.drawString("Fruit No. 1", x, y);
logo.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
```

Whenever you change or draw an image, you'll also want to call in the main method:

`panelone.repaint();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I've never used the drawString or drawImage before. So I really don't know how it actually work, I have just reviewed it, and I'm barely starting to learn the use of GUI, swing and those kind of attributes. Even my programming vocabulary is very poor, but I'm trying my best to learn this. I tried the "window.add(panelone); but it didn't worked. Do you want me to post my code from that class, so you see what I'm trying to do. Maybe it will help us much more.

Comment: Who knows, maybe the image is there, but probably I just need to set the dimensions of the JLabel or JPanel.

Comment: You can definitely post more code if you want help. I'll be glad to assist.

Comment: The drawImage really worked. All I needed was to create a constructor in a separate class. I still want the icon to be positioned to the left, but it won't move from the right. So I'm trying to figure that out right now.

Comment: If things aren't budging on anything in swing (JPanels, JFrames), you need to make sure that you aren't using any LayoutManagers on that component. That means you shouldn't have that `SwingConstants.LEFT` anywhere or anything such as that. Also make sure your window and panel size are being set to the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support expanding the "~" path directive.

Try this...

```
try {
  File file = new File("~");
  System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
  System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
} catch (IOException exp) {
  exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think you will find that it doesn't point to the users home folder.

Instead, you should be using `System.getProperty("user.home")`

```
logo = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "/resources/CherryBoom.png");
```

Now, having said that, I would strongly encourage you to use `ImageIO` over `ImageIcon` as you will get better feedback when something goes wrong.

Check out [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: I'm working on it, I'm trying to build the ImageIO constructor in a separate class, and I'm going to try to use it. I hope it works. By the way, thanks :D.